# Accessing and Updating Models with Django on Google-App-Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

What are the different options, with pros and cons, for periodically adding records to a Django app hosted on GAE?

1. Use a custom django management command on the remote datastore
2. Write an API in Django that exposes the datastore to be updated
3. Use a cron task on GAE to update
4. (am I missing anything else?)

## 1: Custom Django management command on "remote"

I'm currently using #1: django-nonrel on GAE and using [custom management/django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) for my models.  For example, this is how I call my custom management command on the remote datastore:

```
manage.py remote mycommand
```

The advantage of this command is ease of development: I can test the the management command locally and simply add "remote" to use it on GAE.

## 2: Write an API in Django that exposes the datastore

I would have to use an extra server with cron to update.

## 3: Use a cron task in Google

I don't know how GAE likes having its users run a scraper periodically.  Also, GAE doesn't have a real cron -- it simply hits a URL at a set intervals.

Comment: Adding what records, why, and in response to what? The best thing to do depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: For example, scraping weather information from multiple websites and each weather report is a single entry

Answer (score 1):

Use a cron job. That's what they're designed for. Whether or not scraping is okay depends on the terms of service on the site you're scraping.

Comment: A "cron job" in GAE is simply telling GAE to hit a URL at a set time.  It's not a real cron

Comment: @Lionel It tells App Engine to request a URL from your app, yes. How is that "not a real cron", and why does it matter?